# Automatically highlight certain cells

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I am looking for a method to highlight certain cells in a table/Grid based on meeting some user defined conditions.

As an example:

```
M = {{-0.6, 0.04, 22}, {0.1, 0.3, 1}, {0.4, 0.05,0.01}}; (*can be much larger *)
```

As purely an example, the data could be formatted as:

```
 TableForm[M, TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y", "z"}, {“correlation", "pValue", 
“tStatistic"}}]  (*number of rows and columns can be very different *)
```

[image: sample data]

I’d like to automatically highlight data which meets a certain user defined criteria say:

```
Abs@Correlation > 0.5 && Abs@pValue ≤ 0.05
```

So the highlighted table would look like:

[image]

Ideally, I’d like a function that I can apply to a Table/Grid….

Comment: Where do you want to use it, `TableForm` has headings but in `Grid` background can by applied via Options.

Comment: Definitely use `Grid`, it's the more modern version for formatting tables. And it's backward compatible in the sense that the output of `Grid` in a text terminal is still formatted the same way as `TableForm`. The converse is also true: `TableForm` output in a notebook is internally formatted using `GridBox`.

Comment: Grid is my preferred method… old habits die hard… that I showed Tableform in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are likely many ways to go about this, but here is one which uses pattens and replacement rules:

```
data = {{-0.6, 0.04, 22}, {0.1, 0.3, 1}, {0.4, 0.05,0.01}};

rule = {a_, b_, c_} /; 
   Abs[a] > 0.5 && Abs[b] <= 0.05 :> 
  {Item[Style[a, Red, Bold], Background -> LightBlue, FrameStyle -> Darker[Red, 0.25], 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}], 
   Item[Style[b, Red, Bold], Background -> LightBlue, FrameStyle -> Darker[Red, 0.25], 
    Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, True}}], c} 

TableForm[data, 
  TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y", "z"}, {"correlation", "pValue", "tStatistic"}}] /. rule
```

[image]

You can also apply this rule to a grid as well:

```
Grid[data] /. rule
```

[image]

Comment: I didn’t realize that Grid has a direct way of handling these cases...

Comment: @Pam it has nothing to do with `Grid` :) it's a replacement rule fitted to your array.

Comment: @chuy I'm not quite convinced that the frame will fit well for  general case.

Comment: @ Kuba Got it after I started to implement it… :-)

Comment: @Kuba I am quite sure it won't, (for example if the cells you want to highlight in this manner are not connected) but this should show how one could use `Item` and the options it takes to style as wanted. Personally I wouldn't use a frame and rely on background.

Comment: @Chuy: I drew a frame just for clarity… background is how I would do it as well.

Comment: @chuy Agree, just wanted to point it out to Pam :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
TableForm[
 Map[If[Abs[#[[1]]] > 0.5 && #[[2]] <= 0.05, {Item[#[[1]], 
      Background -> LightBlue], Item[#[[2]], Background -> LightBlue], #[[3]]}, #] &, M], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y", "z"}, {"correlation", "pValue", "tStatistic"}}]
```

[image]

Grid has, as *Kuba* noted, a direct way of doing this, check the documentation.

If you want to do this on an *existing* tableform by naming columns and conditions, you'll need to parse the fullform of it, generate a list of column name to list entry mappings, and "inject" the changes. Not sure if that's worth the effort vs just manipulating the base data.